# Upside down camera preview byte array

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, nexus6

I have a camera application which is locked to landscape. When needed I rotate the raw bytes gotten from on `onPreviewFrame()` and use them to encode a video.

This approach however fails in the Nexus 5X and 6 devices, because their reversed sensor gives me upside-down frames.

As rotating the preview won't help me in this case, as described [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation(int)):

> This does not affect the order of byte array passed in
>   onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera)

I'd like to know if there's any way to detect that the camera sensor is reversed and/or the raw frame is upside down, so an extra correction is added when rotating them.

Comment: We have the same problem, also with Camera2 API. It appears that [CameraInfo.orientation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html#orientation) and [CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_ORIENTATION) do not give correct information about true sensor orientation (we get 90 for both back and front camera on Nexus 6). So far the only option we know of is having a list of "special case devices".

Comment: I noticed that the majority of the phones that I have available for testing return 90 for back-facing camera and 270 for front-facing cameras. I'm wondering that this is an indicative of its rotation.

Comment: It appears this is correct. On Nexus 6, front camera returns 90, and on other devices it returns 270. Maybe this can be used for determining orientation. Check also [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13176590/213057)

Comment: Thanks for the link, seems pretty good!

Comment: This might help you https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-camera-orientation-made-simple

Answer (score 1):

the camera sensor of the Nexus 5x and 6 are rotated 180 degrees. A lot of apps had this problem when the device was released. You should take this into account while creating a camera app and set your surface rotation accordingly.

For more information go to
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35431231/1492034